# How to hide/remove some panels, Menu's, trays and some controls from end-user XtraReports Winforms Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, report

How I need to hide MDI Controller, Main Menu, Component Tray, Layout ToolBar, Formatting ToolBar from End-User and I want to show few tool like Label, Line, Picturebox, CheckBox remaining I want to hide from End-User. How to complete this task ?

```
    designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.NewReport, DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.CommandVisibility.None);
    designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.OpenFile, DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.CommandVisibility.None);
    designForm.ActiveDesignPanel.SetCommandVisibility(ReportCommand.SaveAll, DevExpress.XtraReports.UserDesigner.CommandVisibility.None);
```

Using this code I can Hide single single controls, But I need to hide that whole controls expect some like save, cut, copy, paste & delete.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve, your requirment you have two options.

1) With devexpress new version 13.2, you can customize your end user designer from your solution only.

http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2553

2) another solution is you have hide panels using following code.

```
Private Sub OnButtonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Create a design form.
    Dim DesignForm As New XRDesignForm()

    ' Open the report to edit.
    DesignForm.OpenReport(New XtraReport1())

    ' Hide the Field List and Property Grid dock panels.
    DesignForm.SetWindowVisibility(DesignDockPanelType.FieldList Or _ 
        DesignDockPanelType.PropertyGrid, False)

    ' Invoke the design form.
    DesignForm.Show()
```

Follow below link.
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument2552
http://documentation.devexpress.com/#xtrareports/CustomDocument5225